# How to add hasMany relationship in sequelize

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm adding **hasMany** association for a model class and getting following error:
**token.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model.**

These are my two models:

```
import { Model, DataTypes, Association } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../db-connection';
import ModelB from './model-b'

class ModelA extends Model {
    public readonly modelBs?: ModelB[];

    public static associations: {
        modelBs: Association<ModelA, ModelB>;
    };
}

ModelA.init({
    column: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'modelA'
});

ModelA.hasMany(ModelB, {
    foreignKey: 'modelAId',
    as: 'modelBs'
});

export default TokenModel;
```

```
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../db-connection';

class ModelB extends Model {
}

ModelB.init({
    uuid: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'modelB'
});

export default ModelB;
```

The code was written following the documentation here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/typescript.html#usage.

I'm using the latest version of sequelize.
Until adding mentioned association the database was working just fine.

Comment: Do you have already build it your DB?, I mean by this, if is already create it and then you tried to add the association.

Comment: No, the db tables don't exist yet, I use ModelA.sync() and ModelB.sync() on app startup to create them.